# Need To Track Referrer via Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api, http-referer, referer

I need to track the referring website when someone comes in, including pick up keywords if I can via the referer. I need to use Google Analytics in Javascript to do this so that it's stored in that GA report, but then I want to also pass this along to my MySQL database to store it with a completed form, for instance. (The site is composed in PHP.)

I heard that Google recently changed the referer for privacy reasons, but I didn't know if that affected Google Analytics API or not. Is it possible to use GA API to get the full referer including the keywords used on the Google search engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recently changed to defaulting to SSL for logged-in users. That means anyone who is logged in will show up as a referring from "https://google.com/".

Google Analytics is smart enough to be able to tell it's organic traffic, but no - you won't get the keywords.

For storing it locally - why? You can export it from GA, and if you're trying to track events, Google Analytics has functionality for that, so you can segment visits that complete your form: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: As for why, it's just that my client has a backend admin set of pages and likes seeing all the referrer and keyword information right along with the form the customer filled out for more information.

Comment: You can do that, then, but you can't associate that data with data from Google Analytics, per section 7 of [their TOS](http://www.google.com/analytics/tos.html). In order to comply with their TOS, you'll have to do this without GA data.

Comment: You could use something like [Piwik](http://piwik.org/), in place of or in addition to GA - or you could write a logfile parser that looks for the POST request of the user who completed the form and provides that data. Getting the inbound traffic source, any associated keyword, and that path through your site for that user should be fairly easy.

Comment: One final point - it is not terribly significant to look at a single user's info like that 99% of the time. Referrers can be trivially faked, and some browsers hide them to begin with. If the data is there, it's *usually* correct. If it's missing, you really can't conclude that they hit your site directly.